# Color Sets and UIColorAttributeTraitStorage error

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I've been trying to make an app written in Xcode 9 for iOS11 iOS9.0-compatible and all of a sudden it crashed with this error on iPhone 4S:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named _UIColorAttributeTraitStorage'
```

Same project runs fine on iPhone 7.

I've changed all [UIColor colorNamed:] as Xcode suggests:

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
        statusBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorNamed:@"MyColor"];
    } else {
        statusBar.backgroundColor = kColorFromHex(0x509E2F);
    }
```

But the error didn't go anywhere. I also didn't find any mention of UIColorAttributeTraitStorage in Apple Documentation or anywhere on the web except some japanese(?) [post](http://www.jianshu.com/p/9bdcf2b278e4). All I understood from this post is that someone probably faced the same issue with Color Set in iOS 10.3 and Xcode 9.

So it seems the problem is in xcassets containing Color Sets. Does this mean there is no backwards compatibility for Color Sets? And that if I add one there's no way to distribute my app for iOS lower than 11.0?

P.S.: I don't have any iOS 10 device, so I don't know if the issue is still there for 10+ since Xcode 9 public release. Can anyone give it a try?

Comment: I could reproduce for iOS 9 and 10. Also on a iOS 11 simulator, I had the following log: `Unable to resolve the color named "my-missing-color-name" from any of the following bundles`

Comment: @Vince, have you any solution for silence this warning?

Comment: @192kb I solved the issue following the first answer. I used a device with iOS 11 to pinpoint which color is an issue and searched for it in my project

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I encountered the same issue when using the new Color sets in Xcode 9 Interface Builder. If you need to support iOS 10 or earlier, don't use any color from Color set in Interface Builder.

So just make sure you don't select any colors above `iPhoneSDK` section in Interface Builder.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The problem was indeed in the storyboard using asset colors. When I changed them to same values added via 'Other' option in the menu you showed (I actually had them all in 'recently used' section but it's pretty much the same) it worked. Didn't even have to change any code, as I already had @available everywhere.

Comment: If you could not find the color causing the issue like me, you can search in storyboards the line `<capability name="Named colors" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>` that declares there is a color set.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1181162/vince  Did you remove it or change capability name?

Comment: I removed from the storyboard file using TextEdit  :         <namedColor name="backgrdNavyBlue">
            <color red="0.11764705882352941" green="0.14901960784313725" blue="0.23137254901960785" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
        </namedColor>
.  I could not find where to delete it in the interface.

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR**;
You may have selected a color from the "Recently Used Color" dropdown that is a defined Color Asset in an other project than the one you are currently using. Make sure that you don't have any selected color in a nib or storyboard that is marked as Missing.

Say that you in "project 1" define a Color Asset and you name it something e.g. "YorkGreen" as in the example below.

That color will show up in the "Recently Used Colors" dropdown **for all other project**. And if you select it (from any other project than "project 1") an `NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException` will be thrown when loading that view (nib or storyboard) and your app will crash.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException',
reason: 'Could not instantiate class named _UIColorAttributeTraitStorage'
```

[image]

[image]

Hopefully it's a bug that Xcode 9 even show Color Assets from other projects and that this will be fixed in a future release of Xcode.

Comment: wow, that's a good thing to know, that there's a bug like that! Ran into this in my different project recently and it's really confusing. Also, I'd recommend checking if there are asset colors in XIB through its code (I used version editor) because for some reason Xcode 9 happens not to show if you're using an asset color or custom, but same RGB.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to answers above:

Unfortunately, there is no quick way to fix this - Xcode does not give you a hint which UI elements have colors from 'Named Colors'. The only evidence is this small warning:

[image]

Here is how to make your life bit easier:

1. Delete reference to your color resource collection from project
2. Check all your .xib files for something like this

[image]

3. Click on it and go to "Other" option menu

[image]

4. Open 'Color Sliders' tab and simply click on any color value

[image]

5. Color will be applied and saved as local value

[image]

Another way to approach the problem:

1. Do steps above to one of your UI elements.
2. Check Git, you will see change like this

   ```
   - <color key="textColor" name="name of you color"/>
   + <color key="titleColor" red="r.rr" green="g.gg" blue="b.bb" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
   ```
3. Open your project in Atom or sublime like a project folder, search for `<color key="textColor" name="name of you color"/>` and replace everywhere

Comment: You can see and edit .xib/storyboard code from Xcode using Version Control tab (good to see when and where color sets were added) or just right-click it in the source-tree and select "Open As -> Source Code"